# Expectation: empty jars

Tags: probability, expectation

there are four jars, A through D, and $N$ balls. What is the expected number of jars that are empty if $N=4$. What is the expected number of empty jars if $N \sim Poisson(4)$ The first part I think I got as $\frac{81}{64}$, but I don't know how the second part differs if at all.

Comment: Are the $N$ balls randomly distributed between the $4$ jars?

Comment: yes. The balls are "thrown" in the jars randomly(with equal probability)

Comment: Let $X_a$ be the indicator random variable such that $X_a=\begin{cases}1&\text{if jar }A\text{ is empty}\\0&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$.  Similarly define $X_b,X_c,X_d$.  Recognize that $E[X_a]=Pr(X_a=1)$.  Further recognize that the total number of jars empty is $X=X_a+X_b+X_c+X_d$ and that the expectation operator is linear.  So... to continue our calculations, what is the probability that the first jar is empty?  I.e. what is the probability that every ball went into a jar different than jar $A$?

Comment: Yes, that is the method I used for the first part to obtain $\frac{81}{64}$. My main question was on the second part and how/if it differs unless you find that my answer is incorrect, in which case I'd be curious to hear your explanation

Comment: The second part is just like the first, except when you go to calculate $Pr(X_a=1)$ it is not simply $(\frac{3}{4})^4$ it is instead $Pr(X_a=1)=Pr(X_a=1\mid N=0)Pr(N=0)+Pr(X_a=1\mid N=1)Pr(N=1)+\dots+Pr(X_a=1\mid N=n)Pr(N=n)+\dots$

Answer (score 0):

The second part has the number of balls $N$ distributed according to a Poisson distribution with mean $4$.  That means there is $\frac {4^ke^{-4}}{k!}$ chance of having $k$ balls.  You just need to do the same analysis you did before for various $k$, multiply by the probability of that value of $k$ and sum them up.

Comment: But there are an infinite number of values of k, so this would imply I have to calculate an infinite series?

Comment: Yes, you will have a series to sum.  I haven't done it.  Certainly the terms will get small quickly so you can stop and have a small error.  You may find you can sum it analytically.